# Coaxing Flask/werkzeug to render a (flask-admin) page from the python shell

Tags: flask, werkzeug, flask-admin, python

Using the python shell I'm poking at [flask-admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org)/[pymongo](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/db_pymongo/)/[flask](https://flask.readthedocs.org) and trying to figure out if I can coax it into dumping the html that it would generate for a given page.

The code I'm pasting into python shell is as follows:

```python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.pymongo import ModelView
from wtforms import form, fields
import pymongo

class UserForm(form.Form):
    dispname = fields.TextField('Name')
    email = fields.TextField('Email')

class UserView(ModelView):
    column_list = ('dispname', 'email', 'username', 'userextra')
    form = UserForm

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['cloud']
app = Flask('putting_a_name_here')
admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(UserView(db['userpgs']))

#app.run(host='0.0.0.0') # If this is uncommented connecting to
                         # http://localhost:5000/admin/userpgsview
                         # properly renders the contents of the mongo
                         # collection 'userpgs' in db 'cloud'
```

(I realize I'm making this considerably more complex by leaving the `flask-admin` and `pymongo`/`flask.ext.admin.contrib.pymongo` in the example, but the `flask-admin` rendering/html is what I'm really trying to understand.)

I haven't been able to find direct documentation on how flask rendering/html is called/used, but by adding some debugging to the library I've been able to see the above code causes blueprint/rule code in flask to run and populate a list in my `app` called `view_functions` with function callbacks (with promising names like `userpgsview.ajax_loopup`, `userpgsview.index_view`, etc).

The `index_view`, which (from other debugging) appears to be bound to url `admin/userpgsviw/` is what I most want to understand, so I started by trying a:

```
>>> app.view_functions.get(u'userpgsview.index_view')()
```

which caused a traceback on the exception `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`

Digging around in the flask documentation on using the [python shell](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/shell/) I found information about setting a context, so I did the following

```python
ctx=app.test_request_context()
ctx.push()
app.preprocess_request()
```

and tried again, resulting in:

```
>>> app.view_functions.get(u'userpgsview.index_view')()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 62, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 62, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 62, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1191, in index_view
    filters),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1062, in _get_url
    return url_for(view, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 312, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 305, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1620, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('index_view', {}, None)
```

And I haven't been able to find any leads on how I might initialize things so `werkzeug.routing` is happy.

Frank, I won't be surprised if I'm coming at this from the completely wrong approach, but I haven't had any luck in finding other documentation I how I should be hand-running flask if my goal is to coax it into generating the html it would create on a html-get of `http://localhost:5000/admin/userpgsview`.

Any ideas would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Flask testing client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#testing) to simulate requests:

```
# Instead of test_request_context
client = app.test_client()
response = client.get("/admin/userpgsview")
# work with response here
```